# How to use LINQ to select and transform a subset of a List<T>

Tags: c#, linq, generic-list

I have a list `List<UserRoles> roles` that has this structure

```
{r:1,u:1,v:3},
{r:1,u:1,v:5},
{r:2,u:1,v:9},
{r:3,u:2,v:10}
```

I am trying to write a LINQ statement that will filter out only the "r"s that have values 1 & 2 and return a collection of ints/strings of "v"s

This is what I am trying to do and my problem is in the part where I want to transform the  into  that holds only the corresponding "v"s.

```
 List<Int32> =  roles.Where(r => r.r == 1 || r.r == 2)
                     .Select(i => new Int32{id = i.v});
```

This doesn't compile with an error that `'id'` is unknown.

the end result that I need is this:

```
List<Int32>

{v:3},
{v:5},
{v:9}
```

Comment: That is impossible, do you want integers or objects with an id?

Comment: List<Int32> =  roles.Where... doesn't name a variable.

Comment: @user2312219, what did you expect **new Int32{id = i.v}** to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sound like you need a list of `int`:

```
 List<int> result = roles.Where(r => r.r == 1 || r.r == 2)
                         .Select(i => i.v)
                         .ToList();
```

In case you have a list of `int` to filter, you can use `Contains` method to avoid lots of `||`:

```
var filters = new[] { 1, 2};

List<int> result = roles.Where(r => filters.Contains(r.r))
                        .Select(i => i.v)
                        .ToList();
```

Or maybe you need `{v:9}`, you can use *anonymous type* with `var` keyword:

```
var result = roles.Where(r => filters.Contains(r.r))
                        .Select(i => new { i.v })
                        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess v is already an int.
So the solution would be as simple as :

```
var result =  roles.Where(r => r.r == 1 || r.r == 2).Select(i => i.v).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is an array of anonymous objects, use this:

```
var res =  roles.Where(r => r.r == 1 || r.r == 2).Select(i => new{i.v}).ToList();
```

This would produce a list of objects with a single property called `v`.

If you are looking for a list of integers, and `v` is an `int` in the original class, use this:

```
var res =  roles.Where(r => r.r == 1 || r.r == 2).Select(i => i.v ).ToList();
//                             note that there's no new here ^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

You've used an annoymous type but then added `Int32` in front of it which is illegal.

```
 List<Int32> results = roles.Where(r => r.r == 1 || r.r == 2)
                            .Select(i => new { i.v }).ToList();
```